# Make field non-editable based on a condition

Tags: list, jquery, column

I have a list with fields for each months like Jan-Dec, so 12 columns in total.

I want to make a field disabled based on a condition like if the current month is June, disable the column (non-editable) of July (current month + 1). I want to do it by using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [SPUtility.js](https://sputility.codeplex.com/) for this one. Just to give you the idea of how this can be done:

```
// Define the current month
// GetSPFields - get an object containing all the fields on the page
var fields = SPUtility.GetSPFields();
for (fieldName in fields) {
    var field = SPUtility.GetSPField(fieldName);
    if (field != currentMonth) {
        field.MakeReadOnly();
    }
}
```

([Ref](https://sputility.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Common%20SPField%20functions))